# add pattern to ggplot boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to be able to manipulate the filling patter for each of my boxplot.
I have the following code that provide me with a boxplot, I tryed to use ggpattern to set a patter, but I am not able to assign to each column of the plot a specific pattern.

I am able to have some pattern using geom_boxplot_pattern, but I am not able to change the type of pattern shown to fit my needs.

Thank to anyone will help,
Best,
Valentina

````
g<-ggplot(data=data, aes(Instr1,seek, color=Instr1)) +
geom_boxplot(color="black", fill=col1,alpha = 0.5,outlier.shape = NA) +
  geom_jitter( position = position_jitter(0.2)) + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("black", "black","black", "black"))+
  stat_summary(fun=mean, geom="point", shape=23, size=4,color="black", stroke = 1)+
  theme_classic()+
  theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x=element_blank())+
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size=20,color="black"),
        axis.ticks.y=element_blank())+
  theme(legend.position = "none")+
  ylim(-1.8, 1.8)``` 



g+ geom_boxplot_pattern( aes( pattern = task )) ```
````

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood your question. This is what I came up with:

First make a new column to assign a task to each of your variables.

Then you can use scale_pattern_manual() and scale_pattern_fill_manual() to manually assign a pattern and a color to each task.

```
#remotes::install_github("coolbutuseless/ggpattern")

library("ggplot2")
library("ggpattern")

plot_data <- iris

## create new column to assign tasks to groups of variables
plot_data$task <- ifelse(plot_data$Species == "setosa", "task1", "task2")

ggplot(plot_data, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_boxplot_pattern(aes(pattern = task, pattern_fill = task), pattern_density = 0.35, outlier.shape = NA) +
  scale_pattern_manual(values= c("task1" = "crosshatch", "task2" = "stripe")) + # manually assign pattern
  scale_pattern_fill_manual(values=c("task1" = "red", "task2" = "lightblue")) + # manually assign colors
  geom_jitter(position = position_jitter(0.2), aes(color=task)) +
  theme_classic()
```

[ggpattern manually change pattern and color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7YkI.png)